# Formating a Grid with Reals "."-aligned

Tags: grid-layouts

I have a table of real numbers and want to format a Grid such that the headlines are centered and the contents are aligned at the decimal point. MWE:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{1, 100}], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 2}]
```

headers:

```
columns = {"one", "two"};
```

Rows:

```
rowsLabels = StringJoin["R", ToString[#]] & /@ Range[5]
rows = Flatten /@ ({rowsLabels, data}\[Transpose])
```

Table:

```
tab = Join[{Prepend[columns, "Text "]}, rows]
```

Then

```
Grid[tab, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}},
 Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Center}, {{Left, ".", "."}}, Baseline}]
```

delivers:

[image]

and

```
Grid[tab, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}},
 Alignment -> {{{Left, Center, Center}, {Left, ".", "."}}, Baseline}]
```

delivers:

[image]

So the second columns is fine, but the first not. Can anyone give me a hint on how I can achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like using a list specification doesn't work for this. Instead, you can use the 3 element list form of [`Alignment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alignment):

```
Grid[tab, Alignment->{{Left,".","."},Baseline, {{1,1},{1,3}}->Center}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use [`Item`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Item) to override the headers:

```
Grid[
    MapAt[Item[#, Alignment->Center]&, tab, {1, All}],
    Alignment->{{Left, ".", "."}, Baseline}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your for this solution, the second one is the one which is very clear to me (one rule - override the headers).

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation you point to for the three-argument form suggests the 3rd argument would be `{{1, 1} -> Center, {1, 2} -> Center, {1, 3} -> Center}}`.  Should I be able to deduce from this that `{{1, 1}, {1, 3}} -> Center}` will work?  If not, what is the actual documentation?

Comment: @Alan The `Alignment` docs are a bit sparse on this topic. If you look at one of the other options, e.g., `Frame`, you will see an example of the syntax I used.